# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at 49.js:1:1) admin.js Uncaught (in promise) Error: Loading chunk 49 failed

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Here Is My webpack.mix.js:

```
// const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/admin/app.js', 'public/js/admin.js')
    .stylus('resources/assets/stylus/admin.styl', 'public/css/admin.css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/invoice.scss', 'public/css/invoice.css');
mix.webpackConfig(() => {
    const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

    const dev = {
        devServer: {
            contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        },
    };

    const prod = {
        output: {
            chunkFilename: 'js/chunks/[name].[chunkhash].js',
            publicPath: mix.config.hmr ? '//localhost:8000' : '/'
        },
    };

    let obj = {
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue'],
            alias: {
                '@': path.join(__dirname, './resources/assets/js/admin'),
            }
        },
        plugins: [
            // new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            //     verbose:false,
            //     cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ['js/chunks/*',],
            // }),
        ]
    };

    return isDev ? {...dev, ...obj} : {...prod, ...obj};
});
```

Hi,everyone I'm Using Laravel and Vue js But when I Want To Go Another Page It Give Me Error.
I don't Know What Type Of Error Is This. I tried So Many Solution But Did'nt  Work. My admin.js file located in public/js/ directory and my 49.js file Located in public/ Directory.
Please Help.